# Excel: Sum values based on values in another column and mapped values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have the following table

[image]

On each day a single sport activity is organized and attending students receive bonus points. Students can attend activities each day to receive points.

Based on existing columns I need to calculate total bonus points for each student (column I)

If in column D I had number of points for that day I could solve this with a SUMIF but as that is not the case I am not sure how to incorporate values from F which I  need for summing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,INDEX(C:C,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & H2 & ",","," & $B$2:$B$7 & ",")),ROW($B$2:$B$7)*{1,1})))))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Edit, based on TomSharpes but with SUMIFS instead of OFFSET.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & H2 & ",","," & $B$2:$B$7 & ","))*SUMIFS($F$2:$F$4,$E$2:$E$4,$C$2:$C$7))
```

[image]

Note: I used SEARCH to remove the case match and bracketed the inputs and checks with `,` so `Ann` is not found in `Anne`

Comment: Neat, SUMIFS is better than using OFFSET plus you have checked for names that could possibly be a substring of another name.

Comment: @TomSharpe but I would not have gotten there if I had not seen yours, credit goes to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(H2,$B$2:$B$7))*N(OFFSET($F$1,MATCH($C$2:$C$7,$E$2:$E$4,0),0)))
```

[image]