# Summing based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a problem similar to the one described in [Excel: Sum values based on values in another column and mapped values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072450/excel-sum-values-based-on-values-in-another-column-and-mapped-values)

Solution there works in excel but unfortunately it doesn't work in google sheets.

How can this be done in google sheets and does anyone know why excel solution is not working in google sheets?

**Edit 1:**
Per request I am duplicating relevant info here:

[image: Image with spreadsheet layout]

On each day a single sport activity is organized and attending students receive bonus points. Students can attend activities each day to receive points.

Based on existing columns I need to calculate total bonus points for each student (column I)

Comment: Relevant details added

Comment: Seems like a question for webapps.stackexchange.com and not stackoverflow... no programming here

Comment: @tehhowch https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:I2

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(--REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))),H2:H8),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C)),E:F,2,0),0)))
```